# getting an error of register adapter in flutter using hive

Tags: flutter

I have created a simple app for storing data using hive and getx as state management

I have followed all the steps but even thought its showing an error like

After coding when I played ...it worked fine...but when I restart the app...it stops showing white background and an error in console....

have u forgotten register adapter...

I have registered adapter in main...eventhough getting this error

error is

Unhandled Exception: HiveError: Cannot read, unknown typeId: 32. Did you forget to register an adapter?

```
class TransactionController extends GetxController
{
  List<TransactionModel> _transactions=[];
  Box<TransactionModel> transactionbox=Hive.box('a');

  List<TransactionModel> get transactions{
    return _transactions;
  }

  TransactionController(){
    _transactions=[];
    for(int x=0;x<transactionbox.values.length;x++)
      {
        var trns=transactionbox.getAt(x);
        if(trns!=null)
        _transactions.add(trns);
      }
  }

  int get countlength{
    return _transactions.length;
  }

  void addTransaction(TransactionModel transaction)
  {
    _transactions.add(transaction);
    transactionbox.add(transaction);
    update();
  }
}
```

this is model class

```
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

part 'transactionmodel.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class TransactionModel
{
  @HiveField(0)
  String id;
  @HiveField(1)
  String detail;
  @HiveField(2)
  bool isExpense;

  TransactionModel({
    required this.id,
    required this.detail,
    required this.isExpense,
});
}
```

this is void main

```
void main() async
{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Directory dir=await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  await Hive.initFlutter(dir.path);

  await Hive.openBox<TransactionModel>('a');
  Hive.registerAdapter<TransactionModel>(TransactionModelAdapter());
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a wrong thing in your code, you're trying to open the Hive box before registering the adapter, you're calling `Hive.registerAdapter` after you already opened the box, change it with this:

```
void main() async
{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Directory dir=await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  await Hive.initFlutter(dir.path);

  Hive.registerAdapter<TransactionModel>(TransactionModelAdapter()); // this should be first
  await Hive.openBox<TransactionModel>('a'); // then this
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```